# Spring boot config log4j2 use web lookup not working

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

My web app is build with spring boot `2.1.2.RELEASE`, i want to use context path as log dir, but get error when spring boot run.

```
ERROR Unable to create file ./logs/agilor/${web:contextPath}/logs.log
```

It look like web lookup is not work.

I have `log4j-web` in pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Application is extend from `Log4jServletContainerInitializer`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends Log4jServletContainerInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Below is my log4j2.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_DIR">./logs/agilor/${web:contextPath}</Property>
        <Property name="PATTERN">[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{10} - %msg%n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${LOG_DIR}/logs.log" filePattern="${LOG_DIR}/logs_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Log4j is expecting the the LoggerContext's externalContext field will contain the address of the ServletContext. Spring Boot uses that field as a flag to indicate that Logging has been initialized. This is a bug. I have created [LOG4J2-2736](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2736) to fix it.

Also, Log4j 2.13.0 was just released. It will let you convert your property to

```
<Property name="LOG_DIR">./logs/agilor/${spring:spring.application.name}</Property>
```

if that is what you were trying to do. You would need to include the log4j-spring-cloud-config-client module to get the SpringLookup.

Comment: Thanks, i use relative path in my project now, i will try your solution later.

Comment: Hi @rgoers the correction of this issue hasn't been added yet a release, right?
I say this because I find no reference to this issue on https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/changes-report.html

Comment: Yes, it was fixed in 2.13.0